# AccessControlException when trying to redeploy webapp to Tomcat using Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, tomcat6, netbeans6.8, accesscontrolexception

I'm getting the following error trying redeploy an webapp on Tomcat from within Netbeans 6.8. It has probably something to do with the new deploy on save and hot swap functionality. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

```
INFO: Error registering wrapper with jmx StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CubeAdSaSim2] Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/CubeAdSaSim2,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission register)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission register)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:568)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrustPermission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1824)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:310)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:805)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.registerJMX(StandardContext.java:5281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4482)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1249)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:377)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to edit `conf/catalina.policy` to include this line:

```
grant {
   permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register";
};
```

Then add to your `CATALINA_OPTS` the following VM argument:

`-Djava.security.policy=/path/to/your/catalina.policy`