# JMX Registration Error with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, permissions, jmx, accesscontrolexception

I have in installed MongoDB on my server and wrote a very small Java program to connect to it:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost");
db = mongo.getDB("testdb"); // testdb doesn't exist, will be created
```

When I run the program, I get this error:

```
WARNING: jmx registration error: java.security.AccessControlException:
    access denied (javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission register) continuing...
```

What could be causing this error?  I am using the MongoDB database driver 2.7.3 supplied by MongoDB.  I have changed the configuration file(s) for MongoDB since installing.

Comment: Can you post your configuration file, as well as your mongod call and parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me that your security policy is not permitting MongoDB from registering its JMX method.  See this question: [AccessControlException when trying to redeploy webapp to Tomcat using Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416812/accesscontrolexception-when-trying-to-redeploy-webapp-to-tomcat-using-netbeans)

It recommends to edit your `security.policy` file to add the line:

```
grant { permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register"; };
```

Then add the following to your VM command line arguments:

```
-Djava.security.policy= <path to security.policy>
```